# install and import num2words in python

Tags: python, import

I'm trying to install and import the num2words package in Python.  I've run the install in command prompt `pip install num2words` and the package shows up in my site packages folder.  However when I go to import it and call it.

```
import num2words
num2words(345)
```

The environment doesn't recognize the import.

Comment: Do you use Python-3.x? Then the package manager is probably `pip3`, so `pip3 install num2words`.

Comment: The package installs successfully using `pip`.  When I try `pip3` it says requirement already satisfied

Comment: @AndrewColluns: `num2words` is a module, and not callable.

Answer (score -1):

You use `num2words` as a function, but `num2words` is here a *module* you imported, and that module is - in this case - not callable.

The `num2words` however has an attribute `num2words` (the same name) and that is a function that returns the number as a word, like:

```
>>> import num2words
>>> num2words.num2words(345)
'three hundred and forty-five'
```

Comment: Sir Willem, does this package not work on windows os, i am not able to import it even in virtual env.

Comment: @SunderamDubey: you should install it, for example with `pip3 install num2words`.

Comment: I have installed it.

Comment: @SunderamDubey: did you use `pip` or `pip3`? Do you use a *virtual environment*?

Comment: Yes, I used virtual env, tried with both `pip` and `pip3` and I am using [virtualenvwrapper-win](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenvwrapper-win/).

Comment: @SunderamDubey: and you did that when the virtual environment was active? You did not name your file `num2words.py` right?

Comment: No sir, my file name is `my.py`.